# Possible to use a parameter like `id` generically in F#?

Tags: f#

Is it possible to have a parameter representing something like `id` (something of type `'T -> 'T`) and use it generically?

i.e. in the below, I have `id_like` that I'd like to be able to operate on objects of any type. However it appears that as soon as I operate on an object of a specific type, the compiler specializes `id_like` and won't allow it to operate on anything else.

Below I get `FS0064: This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations` when I operate on `a`, and then a compile error when I try to operate on `b`.

```ml
let f (id_like: 'T -> 'T) (a: int) (b: bool) =
    let a1 = id_like a
    let b1 = id_like b
    a1, b1

let _ = f id 0 false
```

If not, is this just an artifact of using Hindley-Milner? Is HM "greedy" in the cases of parameters holding functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not allowed, because it would make type inference undecidable. The resulting language is equivalent to [System F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F) (polymorphic lambda calculus).

Instead, Hindley-Milner type systems provide ["let-polymorphism"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system#Let-polymorphism): Only values bound in a `let` construct are polymorphic:

```ml
let id x = x
  in ... (id 3) ... (id "text") ...
```

The parameters in lambda abstractions (i.e. function definitions) are monomorphic.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like "let polymorphism" is only required for type inference though. Do you know if there's a technical reason this is also impossible when the type is explicitly annotated? Or is this something that could potentially be added to the compiler?

Comment: F# uses .NET generics, so I don’t think this would be possible. It’s not supported in C#, either.

Comment: Thanks also for the education. I've been working off and on (mostly off) for a couple years trying to make a type inference engine to do just this, which was the real motivation behind the question. (And trying to do it without referencing anything so I could see what I could come up with). Nice to know that it already has a name and it's provably intractable and I can move on to my next project.

Answer (score 2):

you can sidestep the issue by wrapping the function in an interface

```
type Id_Wrapper() = 
    member __.Apply<'a> (x: 'a) = id x

let g (id_like : Id_Wrapper) (a: int) (b: bool) = 
    let a1 = id_like.Apply a
    let b1 = id_like.Apply b
    a1, b1
```

the the type is inferred on each application of Apply, which can then be different types

this code does compile